# 'dispose' vs 'dispose of' & « disposer » vs « disposer de »

Tags: english, etymology, comparative-linguistics, french

> [[Source:]](http://snarkygrammarguide.blogspot.com/2012/11/dispose-vs-dispose-of-grammar-police.html) [D1.] **dispose (v.)** - (a) to arrange in order; (b) to lean toward or incline (typically used as a past participle).  ...
>   [D2.] **dispose of (phrasal v.)** - (a) to throw away or discard; (b) to settle or attend to.

1. How and why does the particle **of** change the definition of **dispose**  from D1 to D2?
Why does D2 require the particle **of**?
I already understand and so ask NOT about the above definitions. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. I recognise idioms' illogic, but [what are some right ways of interpreting this idiom, so that it feels reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

2. « **de** » in French   roughly means   **of** in English. But contrary to D2:

> [D3.] [« disposer **de** »](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/disposer) = have (at your disposal).

How did the particle « **de** » (= **of**) induce opposite definitions (D2 and D3) for the same root verb (though in two different languages)?

Comment: "dispose (v.) - (a) to arrange in order;" I've never heard of this! I have heard of the second sense "to lean toward or incline", but I would turn "typically" into "always" What dictionary is that from?

Comment: @curiousdannii I forgot to cite the source; I've updated the OP. Thanks for alerting me.

Comment: Well your source doesn't explain where they got it from either...

Comment: @curiousdannii What about definition 2 at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dispose: 'Arrange in a particular position:' ? Please advise if this helps?

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53054/6700) might have some of the information you're looking for. Combined with the "motion away from" sense of "of", "dispose of" makes sense: putting things into their proper place—away from here, possibly in the garbage. "De" in French only corresponds to English "of" in that both long ago expanded into catch-all prepositions.

Comment: @BenKovitz Thanks. I upvoted it and have read it.

Comment: In French there can be an idea of doing/using as one wishes. E.g. in the military, 'vous pouvez disposer' means 'dismissed!' And when you can use something as you wish, it includes getting rid of it.